# Openstack Neutron: How to update port vif-model using update_port() api

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-neutron

I wanted to update vif_model of already created port. I use following command in CLI

```
neutron port-update --binding:vif_model=avp <port_id>
```

How to achieve the same using python apis of neutron.
I'm trying to use update_port() api. But not sure about parameters.

```
>>> from neutronclient.neutron import client
>>> neutron = client.Client('2.0', endpoint_url=neutron_endpoint, token=tok)
>>> help(neutron.update_port)
```

gives below hint :

> Help on function with_params in module neutronclient.v2_0.client:
>
> with_params(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: Is that a valid command line?  Looking through the [API reference](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-networking-v2-ext.html#port_binding-ext) I see support for `binding:vnic_type`, `binding:host_id`, and `binding:profile`, but nothing for `binding:vif_model`.

Comment: I am using Windriver Openstack Havana release. This is windriver's addition to port since they are supporting accelerated virtual port (avp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the [Nova](https://github.com/openstack/nova/blob/master/nova/network/neutronv2/api.py#L360) source for an example of how the `update_port` call is usually used, and it looks like you would call it something like this:

```
client.update_port('1fe691a6-f3a0-4586-b126-9fabb11e962a',
                   {'port': 
                     {'binding:vif_type': 'avp'}})
```